# fatal error with a simple swift program

Tags: swift, error-handling

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

func randomnumber (low:Int,high:Int )->Int
{
let range = high - (low-1)

return (Int (arc4random()) % range ) + ( low - 1)
}

let answer =  randomnumber(low: 0, high: 100)
var turn  =  1




while (true)
{
print  ("Guess #\(turn): enter a number between 0 and 100")

let userinput  = readLine();
if let guess:Int = Int(userinput!)
{
 if( guess<answer )
  {
   print("choose a higher number")


  }
  if ( guess>answer )
   {
  print ("choose a smaller number")

    }
  if( guess==answer)
  {
   print("wohoo you won")
   break;
  }
  }
  }
```

this code is about a simple  game using swift , by having a random number and then putting an input and if this input is bigger than the random number we have to choose smaller number and the opposite if we choose a smaller number and its still not equal to the random number and if it's equal to the random number you win.
this error appears :
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I don't think this `if let guess:Int = Int(userinput!)` is a safe way to unwrap optionals. Where do you declare `userInput`?

Comment: Guess #1: enter a number between 0 and 100
@mat

Comment: do i need to declare it before i use it? how should i declare it ? i'm totally new to swift so i'm sorry if i seem dumb @mat

Comment: Swift uses type inference so here you do not need to explicitly declare it as an Int.  However, what is the function "readLine()"?

Comment: Are you running this in Playgrounds or as a console application? Because readline() does not work with playgrounds, only console applications.

Comment: @TristanBeaton nope i'm running it through a playground

Comment: Well that is what your problem is. Playgrounds doesn't give the user the opportunity to enter data, so the readLine() will always return nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tristan Beaton pointed out, `readLine()` doesn't work on playground hence your userInput is always nil.

1. CREATE A COMMAND LINE TOOL APPLICATION

[image]

2. CHOSE SWIFT WHEN YOU SAVE
3. COPY AN PASTE YOUR CODE
4. RUN AND PLAY
   [image]

Also be really careful when you force unwrapping. That's always a crash waiting to happen ;) You can read this [tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/0/12/optionals)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this in a Command Line Tool and it worked. Also don't force unwrap optionals since you can just check if they have data without crashing the app.

I have added continue statements within your other if statements. Although it isn't really needed in this case, it is good practice to have it so that any code after the continue doesn't get executed. It just saves a bit of computing power.

```
import Foundation

func randomnumber(low: Int, high: Int) - >Int {

    let range = high - (low-1)

    return (Int(arc4random()) % range) + (low - 1)
}

let answer =  randomnumber(low: 0, high: 100)

var turn  =  1

while (true) {

    print("Guess #\(turn): enter a number between 0 and 100")

    if let userinput = readLine() {

        if let guess:Int = Int(userinput) {

            // Putting this here will only increase the guess count if their input in a number.
            turn += 1

            if guess < answer {

                print("choose a higher number")

                continue
            }

            if guess > answer {

                print ("choose a smaller number")

                continue
            }

            if guess == answer {

                print("wohoo you won")

                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the console output

[image: This is the console output]